# Arduino with servo and RTC

Tags: arduino, real-time-clock, servo

I am making a project that involves a RTC and a servo motor so that it only turns on at a certain time. A snippet from the loop is:

```
void loop() {
    DateTime now = rtc.now();
    if (DateTime == 19:10) {
        //Some stuff
    } else {
        return();
    }
}
```

and my error is:

```
Arduino: 1.6.8 (Windows 10), Board: "Arduino/Genuino Uno"

C:\Users\User\Documents\Arduino\Servo_motor\Servo_motor.ino: In function 'void loop()':

Servo_motor:36: error: expected primary-expression before '==' token

  if (DateTime == 19:10) {

               ^

Servo_motor:36: error: expected ')' before ':' token

  if (DateTime == 19:10) {

                    ^

Servo_motor:45: error: expected primary-expression before '}' token

  }

  ^

Servo_motor:45: error: return-statement with a value, in function returning 'void' [-fpermissive]

Servo_motor:45: error: expected ';' before '}' token

Multiple libraries were found for "RTClib.h"
 Used: C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries\RTClib
 Not used: C:\Users\User\Documents\Arduino\libraries\arduino_786051
exit status 1
expected primary-expression before '==' token

This report would have more information with
"Show verbose output during compilation"
option enabled in File -> Preferences.
```

I am really confused. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume you're using the Adafruit RTClib located [here](https://github.com/adafruit/RTClib), as this is likely the one accessible from the IDE, or that a tutorial will use. It's also a fork of the other available RTClib, so this answer is likely to pertain to both.

If you check [RTClib.h](https://github.com/adafruit/RTClib/blob/master/RTClib.h), you will find the publicly available methods for `DateTime` and all the RTC classes. If you do so, you'll notice that there is no `operator==` method, and in general this means that you can't use that as a form of comparison.

In order to do what you want, you need to use `DateTime.minute()` and `DateTime.hour()` and compare them separately. In your loop block it would look as follows:

```
void loop() {
    DateTime now = rtc.now();
    if (now.hour() == 19 && now.minute() == 10) {
        //Some stuff
    } else {
        return;
    }
}
```

However, this has the possibility of running the code in question quite a few times, as this check will succeed every time the loop runs during the minute following the RTC ticking over to 19:10.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're comparing the the type with a constant (time without quotes).

Dont you mean something like this?

```
if (now == "19:10") {
```